# Can I cancel out quotient function safely?

Tags: functions

Can you actually cancel out the numerator and denominator?

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3-8}{x-2}$$

This function is not defined at $x=2$ so the domain of it is "all real numbers except 2".
$f(x)$ can be rearranged into

$$\frac{(x^2+2x+4)(x-2)}{x-2}$$

When I cancel out the $x-2$, I get $x^2+2x+4$ which is defined at all real numbers. Let $g(x) = x^2+2x+4$. Are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ different functions?

Am I correct to say $f(x)$ is not continuous at $2$, because I can't find $f(2)$?

I am curious about this because I saw this guy at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tKq2NL0GJ4 You can scroll to 4:00 minute where he tries to find continuity of f(x) at x=2. I think that his method is incorrect because f(2) is undefined and you should answer that f(x) is not continuous x=2 immediately. **Am I right?**

Comment: MSE is quite serious already, wrong answers are commented to get edited and downvoted if that doesn't happen.

Comment: The question in bold is a good question. I think also you have received at least one good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, $f$ and $g$ are different functions since they don't have the same domain.

And, yes, $f$ is not continuous at $2$ because it is not defined at $2$.

---

If we talk about limits then you can use the fact that if $f(x) = g(x)$ except at $x=a$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} g(x).
$$
So now you note that for any $x\neq 2$, you indeed have
$$
\frac{x^3 - 8}{x-2} = x^2 + 2x + 4.
$$
And so
$$
\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x^3 - 8}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to 2} x^2 + 2x + 4 = \dots
$$

Comment: This is kind of good answer I'm looking for.
Because I saw this guy at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tKq2NL0GJ4
You can scroll to 4:00 minute where he tries to find continuity of f(x) at x=2. I think that his method is incorrect. Am I right?

Answer (score 7):

Good question. The functions $\frac{x^3-8}{x-2}$ and $x^2+2x+4$ are equal for all $x$ **except at $x=2$,** where the first function is undefined, and the second function is $12$.

However, if you are taking the limit of the first function as $x \to 2$, all you care about are the values of the function at $x$ **near $2$**; the value of $x$ **at $2$** is irrelevant when taking the limit (even if it is undefined there like this case). So canceling is ok in this case.

Comment: I do not mean about finding its limit. I mean will f(x) stay the same after cancelling out the x-2 or not. In the video, she canceled it before taking limit. That changes the meaning of f(x).

Comment: Please change your answer according to my edited question if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't ask about what is the limit of f(x). Please see the question again.

Comment: @off99555 My first paragraph answers your first question: they are different functions because they do not agree at $x=2$. Your justification for $f$ not being continuous at $x=2$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just not sure that you understand my question because I'm not a native English speaker and I can't type in English fluently.